# File not found error for a QML file inside a Qt resource

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qml

**.pro**

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/qmlDeploy
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

TEMPLATE += app
QT += qml

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

RESOURCES += \
    resource.qrc
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    //view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("qml/qmlDeploy/main.qml"));
    view.setSource (QUrl::fromLocalFile("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**resource.qrc**

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">

<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>qml/qmlDeploy/main.qml</file>
</qresource>

</RCC>
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100; color: "red" }
```

### Problem statement:

**When I compile the above programs using QtCreator the following error is shown:**
**Error:**

`file:///home/ppp/documents/test/build-qmlDeploy-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/qrc:/main.qml: File not found`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QUrl::fromLocalFile ()` is simply not meant to be used with Qt Resource, as obviously resource bundle is **NOT** local file, and also, QML file is not at the root of Qt resource file so you have to add the path before it : so just use `QUrl ("qrc:/qml/qmlDeploy/main.qml")` !

*PS: If you want to avoid long paths, like this, just move the `.qrc` file in the same dir as QML files, and you will have shorter URL.*

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is in this line:

```
view.setSource (QUrl::fromLocalFile("qrc:/main.qml"));
```

You have your bad URL syntax. You are trying to open a file in `qrc:` directory.

It should be like this:

```
view.setSource (QUrl("qrc:///qml/qmlDeploy/main.qml"));
```

Because `qrc://` is the URL prefix, `/` is the root prefix, `main.qml` is the file inside it.

Comment: that didn't help , i tried it just now. error is still there.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius error is the same? if it is try cleaning the project and doing a complete rebuild.

Comment: do i have to change something in the qrc file too?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius try this one