# How to load qt quick ui form from QtQuickWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-quick

I Have a `qt quick ui form`, which contains two files: `LogPanel.qml` `LogPanelForm.ui.qml`

`LogPanelForm.ui.qml` file:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    id: item1
    width: 800
    height: 600
    property alias btnAdd: btnAdd

    Button {
        id: btnAdd
        text: "add"
    }
}
```

`LogPanel.qml` file:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

LogPanelForm {
    btnAdd.onClicked: {
        console.log("1")
    }
}
```

I want to load this `quick ui form` from C++ code:

If I set source `LogPanel.qml` :

```
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget();
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/qml/LogPanel.qml"));
view->show();
```

The **form controls** will not show. And there's error message:

```
file::/qml/LogPanel.qml:5:1: LogPanelForm is not a type 
    LogPanelForm {
    ^
```

If I set source `LogPanelForm.ui.qml` :

```
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget();
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/qml/LogPanelForm.ui.qml"));
view->show();
```

The **onClick event** in `LogPanel.qml` will not be called.

How should I load the form from C++ code, that both controls and event handings will work?

Comment: `QUrl::fromLocalFile` - why you use it for resources?

Comment: Because the method signature is `void setSource(const QUrl&);`.

Comment: Why not just `QUrl(":/qml/LogPanel.qml")`? It will do implicit convertion, depending on your string url. I'm not sure that it will help, but anyway...

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but this is not corrent. The file can not be found.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry!  You're right. The url is not corrent. It should be like `QUrl("qrc:/qml/LogPanel.qml")`, not your sample code.

Comment: This is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968058/file-not-found-error-for-a-qml-file-inside-a-qt-resource)

Comment: So I'll move comment to an answer, with some bonus note ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `QUrl::fromLocalFile` instead of implicit version of `QUrl`. Problem is in actual url. It should start with `qrc:/` as you already have researched.

Also, there is a usefull API for managing resources: [`QDir::setSearchPaths`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setSearchPaths) (or `QDir::addSearchPath`). It may help to manage your paths. For example, you can load resources from real folder in debug, and from resources in release, but keeps all string references in code without changes (like `myQml:/something`).

Answer (score 1):

you have to load your .ui.qml file in your qml file:

QmlOne.qml:

```
       Window {
           QMLTwo{ //This your ui.qml file
           anchors.fill: parent
      }
```

Greetings,

Ben

Comment: Thanks. I add a new file `LogPanelWindow.qml` as you post, but there's still error message `file::/qml/LogPanelWindow.qml:5:5: LogPanel is not a type`.

Comment: Could you please show me the code how you add the LogPanel?

Comment: MainForm.ui.qml:

`Item {

    width: 1200
    height: 1000
    //color: "#2010ff"
    property alias btnAdd: btnAdd
    Button {
        id: btnAdd
        x: 113
        y: 160
        text: qsTr("Add")
    }
}`


main.qml:


`MainForm{
        anchors.fill: parent
        btnAdd.onClicked: console.log("[] clicked")
    }`

This works for me without any error

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. The QUrl should be `QUrl("qrc:/qml/LogPanel.qml")`.

Comment: Yeah sure, sorry first I searched the fault in the qml files.

Comment: Thank you all the same! You test the demo, so I guess there's something wrong with load path.